# Tool to show unique styles in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Just like in Word you can see which styles are in use

e.g. Arial 10pt Bold Center, Tahoma 12pt Italic

Is there a way to do this easily in SSRS?

I have lots of small textboxes in a report that I've inherited and want it to be consistent

Comment: You can always see the Font details by clicking F4 on textbox or in the toolbar options you can see font properties.Try to click IN the textbox and right click on To Create placeholder. In the dailogue box you will see font ,Alignment and other properties

Comment: Dailogue box, is that for Welsh users?

Answer (score 0):

I may have some bad news for you. As far as I know, **there is no support for "styles"**, as in "seperated from the content" like CSS is from HTML or the MS Word 2007/2010 styles.

All the styling properties such as font are set on each item individually. Even if you click a row in a tablix and change the font, behind the scenes the designer will set this property for each cell in that row individually.

However, if you aim to make things consistently, it may help to open the RDL in the code editor (or your favorite text editor). It's just an XML file, and you can recognize font items like this:

```
<Style>
  <FontFamily>Arial Black</FontFamily>
  <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
</Style>
```

With some clever search-and-replace-fu you may be able to at least do things like standardize the font family, e.g. replace "Tahoma" with "Verdana" throughout the RDL.

With some Googling I found [this related blog post](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/11/how-to-implement-style-sheets-in-your.html) by someone who got creative and worked around this limitation of SSRS, implementing some kind of pseudo-style-sheet. This may help you further if you really are set to do something similar.

Comment: No, that much I already knew which is why I asked for something to show 'styles in use'. It's shockingly bad and hasn't changed since I first started using it back in 2004(?) Someone in MS should be fired for this. From a cannon. I think it's going to boil down to some scraping of rdl/xml which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger ;-) .... not even sure if they fixed this in SSRS-2012 or not...

Comment: I think MS are more concerned with forcing a pointless gorilla-arm OS on the world right now rather than righting their existing wrongs. Could be worse, could be using Crystal...o_O